# How to merge/encode a categorical feature's unique values in a regression problem

Tags: regression, feature-selection, feature-engineering, categorical-encoding

A feature contains more than 10 unique values in my case, and I want to merge them to improve my model speed. The problem is I don't know how to merge them in a scientific way.

Now, my idea is to merge them by violin plot(feature-response): if these unique values have similar distributions, then I can merge them together.

However, if there are many unique values, it is hard to make the decision by eyes.
an example of my case is the following picture.

[image]

In a classification problem, I will set dummy variables and add them all in the random forest model, then I merge them based on the importance.

But now my case is a regression problem, so I don't know what metrics can help me make the decision and how to calculate them. help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

Ten unique values is not much, and if speed is an issue, it could be solved otherwise, such as by encoding with sparse matrices.  But if you go with your idea of merging levels, why not use a method like *fused lasso*, see for instance see the tag [fused-lasso](/questions/tagged/fused-lasso).